# What is the algorithm of PGP to encrypt messages?

Tags: public-key-encryption, sign, pgp, encryption-asymmetric

> Is there any documentation that explains what are the mathematical algorithms used in PGP to encrypt a message (key generation, converting a message into a number, signature...) ?

For example, suppose that I have a friend who is using a third-party software to encrypt and decrypt messages with PGP, and I want to send him a message, e.g. "Hello my friend!", and I want to encrypt the message myself without using a third-party software. How do I generate my pair of keys, and how do I calculate the signed-encrypted message ?

I aware about asymetric encryption, DSA, RSA, SHA-1, etc... but I can't find any documentation about PGP algorithm.

Comment: PGP and GPG are software solutions not algorithms. They use all the popular algorithms such as RSA, AES and a couple others..

Comment: I would like to know which popular algorithms it is using, in which order and which parameter.

Comment: You might want to look at the RFCs; not an easy read though. -https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc1991#section-6.5.1                                         -https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc2015

Answer (score 1):

PGP and some other derivated software initially used a closed file format. This was a problem, so P. Zimmermann (that wrote and first published the software named PGP **in year 1991**) wrote a RFC (with co-authors W. Stallings and D. Atkins), titled *PGP Message Exchange Formats* published in year 1996 by the IETF: this RFC number is ... **1991** (easy to remember: PGP first published in 1991, RFC number 1991, repeat after me, ...).

Note that this RFC is **not** a standard: it is only an **informational** document. Nobody should claim conformance to it. It has been published only because, as stated by Postel, Huitema, and Crocker in RFC-1796: *Rather Document Than Ignore*.

This RFC has been obsoleted by RFC-2440, titled *OpenPGP Message Format*, **and this one is a standard**. The latter has been obsoleted by RFC-4880, with same title and same category (standards track). And finally, RFC-5581 added some minor updates to RFC-4880. These specifications explain which algorithms are used and how to use them to format messages.

There are many implementations of this format and cryptographic operations. You will even find JavaScript implementations. A notable online service that lets your browser use JavaScript to manage Open PGP messages is available here: https://keybase.io This is not an implementation of a protocol: you have to copy/paste the  encoded ciphertext to you mail user agent, for instance, if you want to send OpenPGP messages built with the help of this service.